# HTML/CSS Query - cant seem to reposition ul elements for mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have run into a slight problem when trying to reposition a list (with 2 items) when on smaller devices. i have a tried a whole host of things, but haven't quite got there yet as I cannot seem to center the list elements on smaller devices.

Basically, I have a title and a list that on large devices have the title and list on the same line (title left, list items inline on the right). Then for smaller devices I want to move the list below the title, keeping them inline (same line) until it is no longer possible, when they would go below one another, but keep it centered within the page throughout this. At the moment I can move the list to the next line fine, and when both cannot fit on the same line, it moves to one on each line. However, I am having difficulty keeping them centered.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/anyd1nuf/

HTML:

```
<body style="overflow: auto;" class="no-touch">
<section class="soundtrack" id="Soundtrack">
        <div class="container">
            <header class="group">
                <h2>Soundtrack</h2>
            </header>
            <div class="carousel-container">
                <div class="responsive-carousel">
                    <ul class="items group">
                        <a href="#"><li class="item">
                            <p>Menu<br />.../p>
                        </li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li class="item">
                            <p>...<br />... - ...</p>
                        </li></a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
 </body>
```

CSS

```
    h2 {

    font-family:arial;
    color:#fff;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-size: 3.5rem; }
    @media (min-width: 480px) {
    h2 {
      letter-spacing: 6px; } }
    @media (min-width: 1000px) {
    h2 {
      letter-spacing: 12px; } }


    .soundtrack {
    background: #000;
    box-shadow: 0px -20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 5.175), 0px 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 5.175);
    min-height: 175px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100; }
    .soundtrack .carousel-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 42px 0 0;
    width: auto; }
    .soundtrack .carousel-container .responsive-carousel  {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: auto;
    }
    @media (max-width: 1000px) {
            .soundtrack .carousel-container  .responsive-carousel   {

            }
            .soundtrack .carousel-container  .responsive-carousel .items   {
                margin: 0 0 0 20%;
            }
        }
    @media (min-width: 1000px) {
        .soundtrack header {
        float: left;
        display:inline-block;
        margin: 50px 5% 0 0;
        }   
    }
    .soundtrack .carousel-container .responsive-carousel .items .item {
      float: left;
      border: 2px solid #fff;
        box-shadow:4px 4px 25px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075), -4px -4px 25px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075);
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 55px;
        margin: 7px 15px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 232px;
        margin: 0 0 30px 0; }
    .soundtrack .carousel-container .responsive-carousel .items .item:hover {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
        color:#000;
        box-shadow:10px 10px 25px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), -10px -10px 25px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);    
    }
      @media (min-width: 480px) {
        .soundtrack .carousel-container .responsive-carousel .items .item {
          margin: 0 20px 30px 0; }

      }
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .soundtrack .carousel-container .responsive-carousel .items .item {
          margin: 0 40px 50px 0; }
        .soundtrack .carousel-container .responsive-carousel .items .item img {
          display: block; }
        }
```

Comment: i think the issue is with float:left in ln:61 and margin: 0 0 0 20%; in ln:50

Comment: When would you like to having them centred? When all of them - title and both buttons are displayed in column? And centred horizontally in a viewport?

Comment: I am looking to center them as soon as they move to the line below the title, at first with both items on the same line centered, then with them vertically above/below one another still centered. I had tried using margin: 0px auto, but moved to try the  margin: 0 0 0 20%; when it didnt do anything

Comment: First, correct your errors. You can't have an `<a>` in a `<ul>`. Then, there are lots of those "asymmetrical" margin styles; of course things don't show in the middle if your left margin differs from your right margin! And add `text-align:center` to the h2. But like I said, the first thing to do is make it correct HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built bit simplified model, and also @Mr Lister comments are right - you had couple of issues in markup.
So you might want to adjust your particular case, but it could go like that:
HTML:

```
<section class="soundtrack" id="Soundtrack">
    <div class="container">
        <header class="group">
             <h2>Soundtrack</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="carousel-container">
            <div class="responsive-carousel">
                <ul class="items group">
                    <li class="item"> <a href="#"><p>Menu</p></a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="item"> <a href="#"><p>Menu 2</p></a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
header, .carousel-container {
    display:inline-block;
}
.items {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
h2 {
    text-align:center;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:3px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
@media (max-width:380px) {
    header, .carousel-container {
        display:block;
    }
    .responsive-carousel {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

And [Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/1jf67phd/1/).
Play with it, and let me know if you have any further difficulties.